# How to test for blocking vs async?

Tags: c++, testing, stl, c++11, future

I am trying to test for blocking vs async using google test/mock.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble coming up with some kind of test to ensure that async is happening in the first case and blocking in the second.

*Is there a way to confirm that std::future is behaving the way it should?*

**CODE**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <future>

static unsigned a_slow_calc()
{
  sleep( 1 );
  return 1u;
}

TEST( Test_future, Ensure_async )
{
  // 1. immediately returns
  std::future<unsigned> answer = std::async( a_slow_calc );

  // 2. std::future::get BLOCKS until the result is ready
  EXPECT_EQ( 1u, answer.get() );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You should use the** `std::launch::async` **launch policy.** Your first function call is not guaranteed to return immediately contrary to the comment you wrote above it.

The default policy is to do the work on this or on another thread. Your current code may pass the test *on your machine* but could fail on the client's machine...

If you use the `std::launch::async` policy then your test is basically testing the C++11 standard. In other words, what you wish to test is already guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: +1 thx for the tip : btw, I understand that's part of the standard, but when possible, I'd like to verify through testing (esp near the cutting edge where gcc may have partially implemented a new feature - been burnt before).

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) on the `future`, with a zero timeout (or very small) and and see if it returns with the value `future_status::timeout`.

Comment: +1 ty - this is a pretty good suggestion - in fact, I followed the link and worked an example using timeouts which passes the test.  Unfortunately, when I ran valgrind's drd on the test, I got a race-condition (which actually makes sense since there are no guarantees with threads and clocks).